# Unable to download the jq package

Tags: java, docker

We are using openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as the base image in a docker image. Getting this jq:1.6-r0 is affected by CVE-2016-4074 and tried jq>1.6_rc1-r0 this as well. But it hasn't resolved the issue as shown below.

[image]

Here is the Dockerfile

> FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine3.9

> ENV PACKAGES="jq>1.6-r0"

Could anyone guide/suggest how can we resolve this issue?

Comment: Try with a newer version of the Alpine image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alpine 3.9 comes with an older (affected) version of jq v1.6-r0

Only Alpine 3.12 and higher comes with the fixed version of jq v1.6-r1

You can see this here:
https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=jq&branch=v3.9

If you are security-aware, you should upgrade your alpine and generally use up to date versions of most things, if not, then you probably have nothing to worry about.

---

In regards to your follow up question in the comment, about upgrading `jq` without upgrading the base image:

1. I do not know of a way to get an official apk package from a newer alpine.
2. As with any other linux, although it is usually better to rely on the official package manager, you can still opt to build from source or download a pre-built binary.

For example, to get the latest available `jq` (version 1.6) on alpine, directly from the [GitHub release page](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.6), you can do this:

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add wget

RUN wget https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-linux64 && \
    mv jq-linux64 /usr/local/bin/jq && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/jq
```

Comment: Our applications used alpine-OpenJDK 8 as the base image. but there is no higher alpine version of OpenJDK 8 in docker hub to update. So checking for alternatives without affecting the existing setup

Comment: Is there any way to install jq v1.6-r1 on top of openjdk:8-jdk-alpine image or Do we must change to alpine higher version?

Comment: I have updated the answer to address your comment